# Define Grid Based on Multiple Item Counts

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Looking to solve a problem I'm having dynamically defining classes using WordPress Advanced Custom Fields' Repeater field. I've done some digging but haven't been able to find a resource with the specificity that I'm looking for.

I'm displaying a series of portfolio images, and depending on how many there are I would like to give certain photos specific class names within the Foundation grid. Essentially I'm looking to do the following:

- For items 1-4: Apply a class of large-6
- For items 5+: Apply a class of large-4
- If only 1 item: Apply a class of large-8

I've been able to get the first two examples to work, but I'm having trouble defining a third set of parameters. I've tried a number of different routes but I'm not sure what's best at this point. See below for a mockup of what I am looking to accomplish, as well as my code example.

Appreciate any advice!

[image: Mockup]

```js
<div class="row portfolio-examples">

 <?php
        if( have_rows('portfolio_examples') ): 
         while ( have_rows('portfolio_examples') ) : the_row();
    $count = 0;
    $work = get_sub_field('portfolio_work');
    ?>
                    
  <?php if ($count != 0 || $count < 4) :?>
        
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns end">
            <?php if( $work ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $work['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $work['alt'] ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
  
   <?php else: ?>
        
 <div class="large-8 medium-8 large-centered medium-centered columns">
            <?php if( $work ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $work['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $work['alt'] ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php 
        $counter++; 
        endwhile;
        endif; 
    ?>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough to me because you say *Apply a class of large* or *Apply a class of small*, but then in your code you use `.large-6` and also `.large-8`.

Anyway, supposing what you're trying to achieve (given your image), your PHP code should be something like this:

```
<div class="row portfolio-examples">
<?php
if (have_rows('portfolio_examples')) :
    /* We need to know the total number
     * of rows in your repeater since you have
     * a case where there's only one item.
     */
    $portfolio = get_field('portfolio_examples');
    $count = is_array($portfolio) ? count($portfolio) : 0;
    $index = 0;
    while (have_rows('portfolio_examples')) : the_row();
        if ($count == 1) :
            /* Place here your code for when
             * there's only 1 item in your portfolio.
             */
            ?>
            <div class="medium"><!-- Medium item --></div>
            <?php
        elseif ($count > 1 && $index <= 3) :
            // Code for your first 4 items
            ?>
            <div class="large"><!-- Large item --></div>
            <?php
        elseif ($count > 1 && $index > 3) :
            // Code for your 5+ items
            ?>
            <div class="small"><!-- Small item --></div>
            <?php
        else :
            // There are no items in your portfolio.
        endif;
        $index++;
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
</div>
```

**Notice:** You were reseting to 0 your *iterator* index (`$count` in your case) in every iteration. Also, you were incrementing `$counter` (not `$count`) which wasn't defined.

Comment: Ah, got too wrapped up trying to simplify my question that it became more confusing. This is terrific and solved my problem. I'll edit the question a bit so that it can be more helpful for others. Thanks so much!